# Concatenating data and text on select mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Fellows,

I'm using PHP and this code:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y'' às ''%H:%i:%s') as data FROM infografico GROUP BY data
```

Displays something like this:

```
(última atualização: 22/09/2016' às '09:37:16)
```

The question is: how can the ' doesn't appear?

Comment: because `''` is treated as an "escaped quoted" by mysql, so `''` is parsed down to `'` for output. It's essentially the same as `\'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one single quotation mark at the beginning and end

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y às %H:%i:%s')

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb Just tried to be funny but I'm not very good at it. You didn't really ask why quotes were showing (yet look at my answer if you wonder why).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y'' às ''%H:%i:%s') as data FROM infografico GROUP BY data
                        ^--start string
                                 ^^--escaped quote
                                       ^^--escaped quote
                                                 ^---end of string
```

The string delimiters are parsed away by MySQL, and then the `''` are parsed down to `'` for output purposes, because they're not string delimiters - they're treated as a literal quote character. If you want more quotes, you need this ugly construct:

```
DATE_FORMAT(data, '''%d etc... ''')
```

e.g.

```
mysql> select '''foo''bar''';
+-----------+
| 'foo'bar' |
+-----------+
| 'foo'bar' |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: sorry but still didn't get how it should be written

Comment: There's a problem. Now it shows (última atualização: '22/09/2016 às 09:37:16') and I don't want the ' to be displayed.

Comment: if you don't want the quotes, then when do you have `''` in the query in the first place?

Comment: Now it's coded like this: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'''%d/%m/%Y às %H:%i''') as data FROM infografico`

Answer (score 0):

From [String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) (emphasis mine):

> There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:
>
> - **A “`'`” inside a string quoted with “`'`” may be written as “`''`”.**
> - A “`"`” inside a string quoted with “`"`” may be written as “`""`”.
> - Precede the quote character by an escape character (“`\`”).
> - A “`'`” inside a string quoted with “`"`” needs no special treatment and need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, “`"`” inside a string
>     quoted with “`'`” needs no special treatment.

But I suspect you wanted to use this other syntax:

> Quoted strings placed next to each other are concatenated to a single
>   string. The following lines are equivalent:
>
> ```
> 'a string'
> 'a' ' ' 'string'
> ```

For that, you are missing spaces:

```
mysql> SELECT '%d/%m/%Y'' às ''%H:%i:%s' as quotes, '%d/%m/%Y' ' às ' '%H:%i:%s' as no_quotes;
+------------------------+----------------------+
| quotes                 | no_quotes            |
+------------------------+----------------------+
| %d/%m/%Y' às '%H:%i:%s | %d/%m/%Y às %H:%i:%s |
+------------------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Of course, as already pointed out, you don't really need to insert quotes manually if you want none.